# How to remove text from vim

Tags: linux, vim, regex

I want to remove all the words that ending with abc

Example:

> 111abc 222def 333abc 444def 555abc 666def

From here I want to delete all the words that ending with abc.

so I tried this

> :s/abc//g

But this will replace only abc

How to delete that all words ending with abc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to remove the whole word, and if your sample is complete, then you want to use this regexp:

```
:s/[0-9]\{3\}abc//g
```

It removes every bit consisting of 3 digits followed by `abc`.

Comment: It's showing E486: Pattern not found: [0-9]{3}abc

Comment: My bad, I forgot to escape the curly braces. Edited.

Answer (score 6):

If all the words you want to delete consist of three digits followed by the character sequence "abc" you can go with @m4673r's suggestion. For a more general approach I'd suggest this instead:

```
:s/\<\S*abc\>//g
```

This will remove any word (regardless of characters/length) that ends with the character sequence "abc" (`111abc` as well as `FOOBARabc` or just `abc`).

Answer (score 1):

**Ansgar**'s answer is plain right.
I'll explain it's parts to make it a methodology more than a recipe because I think that regular expressions are somehow cryptic.

```
:s/\<\S*abc\>//g
```

is a vim substitution command.
It means "in the current line (use %s for *all* lines) substitute the matches of the regular expression `\<\S*abc\>` (delimited by the first two "/"s by the text contained between the last two "/"s, i.e., nothing. The ending "g" is for global and means to replace all the matches instead of only the first one.

The regexp is enclosed in escaped angle brackets `\<` and `\>`. These are *word* boundaries, meaning that the regexp will match text only within single words. Think that vim will split the text in words before attempting to match each one.
The escaped uppercase S is for non-witespace. `\s` (lowercase) matches whitespace (spaces and tabs) while `\S` (uppercase) matches all other.
Hence, `\S*` means "non-whitespace characters zero or more times".
The `abc` part simply matches that exact characters sequence.

Putting it all together, the regexp matches whole words made up of any sequence of characters followed by `abc`, as **max** wanted.

Because of the way vim thinks of words, the *any sequence of characters* will not contain spaces and other characters that are word boundaries. The *other characters* list depends on the file type being edited and can be seen typing `:set iskeyword` <kbd>enter</kbd>. This is the information used to split the text in words.